# Joining tables without nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure how to explain what I need but here's the data first:

```
Table 1
District 
-1
3
2
1
3

Table 2
ID       ID_Name
1        Main 1
2        Main 2
3        Main 3
```

How do I join the tables so that it looks like this?

```
District 
-1
Main 3 
Main 2
Main 1
Main 3
```

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: `code left OUTER JOIN 
 Pubworks.dbo.District ON Pubworks.dbo.District.ID = 
        Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID`

Results: 
`District
NULL 

Main 3 

Main 2

Main 1

Main 3 `

Comment: Take some time to understand outer joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  LEFT, RIGHT, and FULL OUTER.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the second column is named `Name` for this, but you can do it with a `COALESCE` and a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Select      Coalesce(T2.Name, Str(T1.District)) As District
From        Table1  T1
Left Join   Table2  T2  On  T1.District = T2.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming table 2 have

```
  Table 2
ID     col2
1        Main 1
2        Main 2
3        Main 3
```

you could use a left join

```
select  table1.Distric,  table2.col2
from table1 
left join table2 on table1.dictrict = t2.ID
order by table2 col2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join:

```
Select coalesce(t2.col, t1.District) from table1 t1
   left join table2 t2 on t1.District = t2.Id
```